# How to maintain the aspect ratio of Grid in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, grid, row

I am working on silverligth 5 and under a situation where I have 3 row  in a grid.
 frst contains some text second contains a Scrollviewer and the third one contains buttons.

I want something like that when i resize the grid (suppose make it smaller) then button(on row 3) must persist but the data inside the scrollviewer (row2) can become smaller(which can be further view by scrollviewer) whereas UIelement on first row also must persist like buttons.

Here is my try of code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource BGBrush_1}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="EOD" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Orange" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="panelScrollViewer" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Height="600">
        <telerik:RadTreeView Name="RadTreeViewObj" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="50" Background="{StaticResource BGBrush_1}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BGBrush_1}" ItemsSource="{Binding EODDataStepsCollection}" SelectionMode="Single" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}">
            <telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding RelatedItems}">
                    // here are some UI elements
                </telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadTreeView>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" FontWeight="Bold" Command="{Binding ButtonCancelCommand}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,10,10,10" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle_Blue}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="80" Visibility="{Binding IsValidateVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ValidateButton" Content="Validate" FontWeight="Bold" Command="{Binding ButtonValidateCommand}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,10,30,10" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle_Blue}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="80" Visibility="{Binding IsValidateVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**How to achieve this** ?

Please see that second button is hidden behind. (only half visible). How to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Change your rowdefinitions to this:

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
```

And remove the fixed `Height` from the ScrollViewer.

The first and last rows will be as small as possible, while the middle row will take up the remaining space.

To avoid the Buttons overlapping, you can position them like this:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="ValidateButton" Content="Validate" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,10,30,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="80"/>
        <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="30,10,10,10"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="80" />
</StackPanel>
```

Note: This will right-align the Cancel button. (I have also placed it to the right of the Validate button)

Comment: Thanks. But its just working for height when i reduce width then after some width button hides.

Comment: @user3085082: What do you mean the Button hides? It will overlap the other if allowed to shrink. Is that it?

Comment: @Troesls please see the snapshot in edited question.

Comment: Personally, I'd define my button grid with 3 columns. Column 0 and 2 with width of 'auto' and column 1 with width of '*'. Place your buttons in 0 and 2. Then as the size changes the middle column adapts to the space available.

Comment: @Mashton It stil do not solve my problem.  I n my GUI when i reduce the size less thn the wisth of my GUI at row 2 (scrollbar) thn it again disapperars the button located in right on reducing height there is no problem.

Comment: @user3085082: I can't reproduce it here (without the Telerik control). My guess would be that it is due to the central ScrollViewer being too wide. The Button will right align alongside the widest element in your Grid (probably the scrollviewer). However, I don't quite understand why the scrollviewer does not shrink to fit the parent. What happens if you replace the Telerik control with `<Rectangle Fill="CornflowerBlue" Width="600"/>`?

Comment: @TroelsLarsen yes you are right when the width is small thn Scrollviewer it makes the button disapper. But why it happens i am not able to understand

Comment: @user3085082: I'm just guessing here, but try setting `HorizontalScrollbarVisibility="Auto"` on the scrollviewer.

Comment: There must be something that is causing the ScrollViewer to not become smaller at a certain point. Your right button will align to the right side of the scrollviewer.